# Estimating penetration depth of projectile in nonhomogeneous material

Tags: forces, density, speed, distance

I need an equation for calculating the penetration depth of a projectile in a non-homogenous material. I have the values for density of each layer and the projectile, speed, and angle. Does anyone know of a good one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can firstly consider the forces that act over the projectile in its path through the material: if consider horizontal motion, it can be resistance of the medium. Depending of the velocity value, you can consider this force proportional to velocity or square of velocity. But, since you are interested in to use the densities of each layer in the material, you must relate the proportionality constant of this force with the density. If I find something about it, I will write it here...